# Can't get element by css selector in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I can't get element by css selector in Selenium using Python so I can't click download. This is my code what is this wrong?

```
link = u''

mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    mydriver.get(link)
    btn = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector("//a[class='button neutral']")
    print link

except Exception as e:
    print "link: {0}, exception: {1}".format(link, repr(e))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `XPath` but not a `css-selector`. Try

```
btn = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='button neutral']")
```

If you want to use `css-selector` try

```
mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button.neutral")
```

Comment: thanks. find_element_by_xpath it is working for me. but css_selector is not working for me.

Comment: if you want to use `css-selector` try `mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button.neutral")`

Comment: You should add your CSS selector comment to your answer. I think that's what OP is looking for.